# Getting a single merged histogram for two different variable but want two different plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Python code for plotting histogram

```
 seaborn.distplot(sub2["S2AQ16A"].dropna(), kde=False);
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.title('Age when started drinking')

seaborn.distplot(sub2["SIBNO"].dropna(), kde=False);
plt.xlabel('No. of Siblings')
plt.title('No. of Siblings who are alcoholic')
```

I expected output to be two histogram for individual variables.But got a histogram where both variable were merged in one. Here is screenshot of output.

[image]

If I run code one by one for plotting histogram for single variable while leaving code for plotting histogram of other variable as comment, I get correct output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plotting both histograms on the same axes. If you want them separate, plot them on different axes. Here's one way of doing it.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1)
seaborn.distplot(sub2["S2AQ16A"].dropna(), kde=False, ax=axes[0]);
axes[0].set_xlabel('Age')
axes[0].set_title('Age when started drinking')

seaborn.distplot(sub2["SIBNO"].dropna(), kde=False, ax=axes[1]);
axes[1].set_xlabel('No. of Siblings')
axes[1].set_title('No. of Siblings who are alcoholic')

plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: @ParasMani if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.